# Are there any dangers of assigning different array elements in parallel?

Tags: c#, arrays, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I have a simple parallel task which writes to separate elements of an array, like so:

```
MyClass[] newObjects = new MyClass[ObjectsPerEdge*ObjectsPerEdge]; // ObjectsPerEdge = const int
Parallel.For(0, ObjectsPerEdge, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, z =>
{
    for (int x = 0; x < ObjectsPerEdge; x++)
    {
        newObjects[x + z*ObjectsPerEdge] = new MyClass(...params...);
    }
});
```

I'm essentially filling up a 2D grid, row by row, where each parallel thread should be filling a row of its own. Assuming my constructor code is all thread safe, are there any dangers to using arrays in this way? i.e. is it safe for different threads to assign different array elements, assuming they won't ever look at the same element?

Comment: It's safe, but it likely won't speed things up as much as you might hope because of [`False Sharing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/october/net-matters-false-sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is actually a case where I think it's helpful, as I'm working on a small number of objects, each of which takes a while to create. In my code, `ObjectsPerEdge` is 5, meaning my array has size 25 and each parallel loop thread handles 5 each (one row in my grid). Hence `Parallel.For` will only iterate 5 times, from z=0 to z=4.

I tested it on a few devices and there is a decent speedup, but will keep trying to see if I've missed anything!

I'm also limiting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 2 as this will run on mobile and I don't want to hog the processor.